# Adding dynamic value in mysql limit

Tags: mysql

I have created a procedure, where I want to add a value in limit function dynamically, Below is my sql query, its not working, can anyone tell me, how to add it dynamically

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateSupervisor() 
BEGIN 
set @counter = 0; 
SET @v1 = "some condition"; 
WHILE @counter <= @v1 DO
 SET @v2 = (SELECT id FROM `employee` where DATE_ADD(last_active_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
             DATE_ADD(last_active_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)=CURRENT_DATE AND employee_group!=3 
             LIMIT @counter,1);
 UPDATE employee 
  SET supervisor = 1 
  WHERE id=@v2; 
 SET @counter = @counter + 1; 
END WHILE; 
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I think your syntax is wrong.
Try `set @counter:=0;`

Comment: There is an end if without and if, limit without and order by is a not a good idea I see no evidence of delimiters being set and I doubt if you need a loop at all (hard to tell based on non working code what you are trying to do)

Comment: Use declared variable for limit rather than user defined variable and provide Sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: The parameter of LIMIT clause is a literal. Use dynamic SQL.